# How to convert arabic date to english date

Tags: ios, swift, calendar, localization, arabic

I have a problem in my application. I am getting a date in this format :

`"الإثنين 2015.5.5 - 16:16 مساء  بتوقيت ابوظبي"`

**Like this below Image-**

[image: Screenshot]

From an API but I want to convert it to the `NSDate` English format.

I found this code by *@dfri*. It converts from English to Arabic but I don't know my API `dateFormat`.

```
// input date in given format (as string)
let inputDateAsString = "2016-03-09 10:33:59"

// initialize formatter and set input date format
var formatter = NSDateFormatter()
formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"

// read input date string as NSDate instance
if let date = formatter.dateFromString(inputDateAsString) {

    // set locale to "ar_DZ" and format as per your specifications
    formatter.locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "ar_DZ")
    formatter.dateFormat = "EEEE, d, MMMM, yyyy HH:mm a"
    let outputDate = formatter.stringFromDate(date)

    print(outputDate) // الأربعاء, 9 مارس, 2016 10:33 ص
}
```

How can I do this?

Comment: I think there is something wrong with the date because it shows 24 hour base but still adds the pm at the end (night in arabic)

Comment: @zombie thank you for your response,But i got it like this "الإثنين 2015.5.5 - 16:16 مساء بتوقيت ابوظبي" :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For an easier conversion I think it's better to remove the additional text
so I filtered the string and kept only the needed numbers

here is my attempt:

```
var dateString = "الإثنين 2015.5.5 - 16:16 مساء  بتوقيت ابوظبي"

dateString = dateString.trimmingCharacters(in: CharacterSet(charactersIn: "01234567890.-:").inverted)

var formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy.MM.dd - HH:mm"

let date = formatter.date(from: dateString)

print(date)

//"May 5, 2015 at 4:16 PM"
```

Answer (score 0):

If your date timezone is the same as the user's current timezone You can use NSDataDetector to detect the date in your string:

```
let ds =  "الإثنين 2015.5.5 - 16:16 مساء بتوقيت ابوظبي"

do {
    if let date = try NSDataDetector(types: NSTextCheckingResult.CheckingType.date.rawValue).matches(in: ds, range: NSRange(location: 0, length: ds.utf16.count)).flatMap({$0.date}).first {
        print(date.description(with: .current))  // "Wednesday, February 21, 2018 at 4:16:00 PM Brasilia Standard Time\n"
    }
}
```